# How to get the latest tweets in the default octopress theme?

Tags: twitter, blogs, octopress

this might be a stupid question but why am I unable to let my tweets show up on my octopress blog? I just switched to octopress and as I read in the documentation, you just have to type in your twitter name in the _config.yml file. Github works fine for me however?

What am I missing?

Comment: ok seems like octopress doesnt support twitter out of the box. have to use widgets from twitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Twitter recently updated their API, ending support unauthenticated JSON. The old API exists, but it's subject to rolling blackouts of the API. You can see the discussion on it on github: [Octopress issue 1099](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/1099). As you've noted, you can get a Twitter widget to do the trick.